# Context In Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm working on creating a basic survey app to better learn backbone. I'm working to make it so that a user can only take a certain survey once. I have this built on the rails side and it returns an error if the same user tries to take the same survey again.

The success and error functions are called correctly. The problem I'm running into is when I try to call @saveSurvey. I'm sure the problem is that this.saveSurvey in the context of the success function isn't actually the context of the view. Any idea how I should pass context to actually call this function?

```
class SurveyMe.Views.SurveyShow extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['templates/surveys/survey_show']

  initialize: ->
    @model.on('all', @render, this)
    @questionNumber = 0
    @questionLimit = @model.get("questions").length - 1
    @completion = new SurveyMe.Models.Completion
    #@listenTo(@completion,'change', @saveSurvey)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(survey: @model, questionNumber: @questionNumber))
    this

  back: ->
    if @questionNumber <= @questionLimit and @questionNumber > 0
      @questionNumber -= 1
      $("#container").html(@render().el)
    else
      Backbone.history.navigate("surveys",trigger: true)

  events:
      'click #answer': 'updateQuestion'
      'click #back': 'back'

  updateQuestion: ->
    choice = new SurveyMe.Models.Choice
    choice.save(
      choice:
        appuser_id: Cookie.get('survey_user_id')
        question_id: @model.get('questions')[@questionNumber]["id"]
        answer_id: "4"
      )
    if @questionNumber < @questionLimit
      @questionNumber += 1
      $("#container").html(@render().el)
      @renderQuestion()
    else
      @completion.set(survey_id: @model.get('id'), appuser_id: Cookie.get('survey_user_id'))
      @completion.save null,
        success: ->
          @saveSurvey()
        error: ->
          alert('fail fail fail')
      Backbone.history.navigate("surveys",trigger: true)

  renderQuestion: ->
    question = new SurveyMe.Models.Question(id: @model.get("questions")[@questionNumber]["id"])
    questionView = new SurveyMe.Views.Question(model: question)
    $('#questions').html(questionView.render().el)

  saveSurvey: ->
    alert('great success')
    @model.save(
      number_taken: @model.get('number_taken') + 1
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CoffeeScript problem.

You need to use the fat arrow (`=>`) syntax to maintain the context of `this` in the success callback.

```
  @completion.save null,
    # Use the fat arrow here "=>" instead of the skinny arrow "->"
    success: =>
      @saveSurvey()
    # You would also need to do it here if you planned to use @ to 
    # refer to the parent context in the error callback
    error: ->
      alert('fail fail fail')
```

You'll need to do this whenever you want to use `@` inside a function to refer to the context of the parent function.

CoffeeScript offers the fat-arrow and `@` shortcut as a convenience for maintaining `this` scope in functions. Behind the scenes it just does all the `_this = this` type of stuff you'd generally do yourself in regular old JavaScript.

Here's the relevant docs: http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow

Comment: Exactly right!  I'm also learning coffeescript while learning backbone.  Probably not the greatest plan ;)

Comment: Nah it's a great plan! Fat arrow is one of my favourite CoffeeScript conveniences. I'm sure you'll love it too once you get the hang.

Comment: You could use `success: @saveSurvey.bind(@)` as well, same effect overall.